# How is finfo class closed?

Tags: php, oop

How is finfo closed when using the object oriented interface? Reference http://php.net/manual/en/class.finfo.php.

Is it necessary to do so?

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
// ... 
finfo_close($finfo);    //This works


$zip = new ZipArchive();
// ... 
$zip->close();  //This works

$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
// ...
$finfo->close();    //Error: Call to undefined method finfo::close()

finfo_close($finfo); //Error finfo_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given
```

Comment: What about `unset($finfo);`?

Comment: @axiac  I was thinking the same thing.  Not sure why some of the interfaces have a `close` method and others do not.

Comment: Afaik the internal handles will be destroyed once the memory claimed by the object is about to get freed: [Source](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/fileinfo/fileinfo.c#222) (The link to the assigned function is clickable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the tests for fileinfo_close](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/0437aa2abf1eb494e4555d7d4dfbdbf566a59bdc/ext/fileinfo/tests/finfo_close_basic.phpt), the PHP guys appear to just use `unset` in order to mimic the behaviour in the OOP version. I couldn't find anything in the code that suggests it is done automatically.

```
--TEST--
Test finfo_close() function : basic functionality 
--SKIPIF--
<?php require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/skipif.inc'); ?>
--FILE--
<?php
/* Prototype  : resource finfo_close(resource finfo)
 * Description: Close fileinfo resource. 
 * Source code: ext/fileinfo/fileinfo.c
 * Alias to functions: 
 */
echo "*** Testing finfo_close() : basic functionality ***\n";
$magicFile = dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'magic';
$finfo = finfo_open( FILEINFO_MIME, $magicFile );
var_dump( $finfo );
// Calling finfo_close() with all possible arguments
var_dump( finfo_close($finfo) );
$finfo = new finfo( FILEINFO_MIME, $magicFile );
var_dump( $finfo );
unset( $finfo );
?>
===DONE===
--EXPECTF--
*** Testing finfo_close() : basic functionality ***
resource(%d) of type (file_info)
bool(true)
object(finfo)#%d (%d) {
}
===DONE===
```

Comment: Destructor: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/ext/fileinfo/fileinfo.c#190 ; `unset()` = no references to that object = destructor call -> http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.destructor

Comment: I guess it makes sense to be there. If you closed the resource through another means, the object would become useless anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need to. For `finfo_open`, you have an OOP style - for `finfo_close` you have not. `finfo_close` only accepts an ressource, not an object.

Maybe this is done automatically by the garbage collector of PHP. But it is not needed to be done by you - there just is no function for it, which can do it.